# How to fix the print statement so that it is in one line instead of two?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I am trying to figure out why my print statement is breaking into two seperate lines rather then just printing in one line. I wrote a for loop that bascially takes in a file with Websites like this

```
example0.com
example1.com
example2.com
example3.com
example4.com
```

and starts from the 2nd line and iterates through the file.

```
with open('examplefile') as second_start:
    next(second_start) 
    for line in second_start:
        print('"hostNames": [{"name":' + ' "' + str(line) + '",' + '" source": "DNS"}],')
```

The output of this is

```
"hostNames": [{"name": "example1.com
"," source": "DNS"}],
"hostNames": [{"name": "example2.com
"," source": "DNS"}],
"hostNames": [{"name": "example3.com
"," source": "DNS"}],
"hostNames": [{"name": "example4.com
"," source": "DNS"}],
```

The output I would like is if the print statment just printed it on one line like this

```
"hostNames": [{"name": "example1.com"," source": "DNS"}],
"hostNames": [{"name": "example2.com"," source": "DNS"}],
"hostNames": [{"name": "example3.com"," source": "DNS"}],
"hostNames": [{"name": "example4.com"," source": "DNS"}],
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
print('"hostNames": [{"name":' + ' "' + str(line) + '",' + '" source": "DNS"}],')
```

to

```
print('"hostNames": [{"name":' + ' "' + str(line).strip() + '",' + '" source": "DNS"}],')
```

The `strip()` will remove and leading or trailing spaces, `\r`, or `\n`.
That being said I would recommend writing your print a little cleaner using f-strings. You need to double up any brackets to escape them though.

```
print(f'"hostNames": [{{"name": "{str(line).strip()}", " source": "DNS"}}],')
```

You can also just do `.rstrip('\n')` if you only want to remove the new line at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can remove newline character from `str(line)` by using `str(line).rstrip("\n")` I know that you can use just `.rstrip()` but specifying `"\n"` will ensure that you're removing **only newline character** keeping other special characters untouched.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the readlines() method , that returns a list containing each line in the file as a list item.

after that you can iterate through this list to get the values you need

```
with open('examplefile', 'r') as second_start:
     lines_list = second_start.readlines()
     for line in lines_list:
        print('"hostNames": [{"name":' + ' "' + line + '",' + '" source": "DNS"}],')
```

Comment: The OP is already doing that via `for line in second_start:`. That being said he is using the line generator instead of loading all lines into memory (like you are recommending).

Comment: sorry for misunderstanding.

then he needs to use str(line).rstrip("\n")

Comment: You should still not use `readlines()` for something like this.

Answer (score 0):

Your file is that:

```
example0.com
example1.com
example2.com
example3.com
example4.com
```

And it is equal to that:

```
example0.com\nexample1.com\nexample2.com\nexample3.com\nexample4.com
```

The \n character is a new line character. Look at that:

```
>>> print("Hello\nWorld")
Hello
World
```

So you should delete \n characters from your strings. You can do it by using **str.rstrip("\n")**

```
>>> s = "abc\n"
>>> s.rstrip("\n")
"abc"
```